# How can I format part of an HTML form to put sections into columns?

Tags: html, css, forms

I was wondering if there is a way to make blocks of HTML form information display in columns, preferably based on screen width, but fixed width of 3 columns would be okay as well.

It would be ridiculous amounts of code to put in here, so I'll just put in one block. Just image this HTML code 30-40 times (with different information in each one) that needs to be in columns. Not the individual line items within the "section-container" div but the whole section.

```
<div class="section-container">
  <ul class="selection-list">
    <div class="item-group">
    <label>What symptoms are they experiencing?</label><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="depPresent[]" id="depPresent" value="anxiety" />Depressed Mood
    <br />Severity: &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="sxDep" id="sxDepMild" value="mild" required />Mild &emsp; 
    <input type="radio" name="sxDep" id="sxDepModerate" value="moderate" required />Moderate &emsp;
    <input type="radio" name="sxDep" id="sxDepSevere" value="severe" required />Severe &emsp;
    <br />Notes:<li><input type="text" name="depNotes[]" id="depNotes" value="" /></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The idea would be that it would look like this instead of in a single column:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: CSS grid or flexbox can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish results using `display: flex` & `display: grid` . You can also use `column-count: 3;` . It will divide the content in 3 parts .
[Read this for more about multi-column](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

> Use `<br />` to break line and `label` for `input` . Using appropriate styles and decoration, you can achieve the desired results .
> Below snippet is for demo only and only certain decoration is used

> Here default `padding` `margin` is removed to have clear view . It is suggested to not to use it but instead remove of the individual properties according to need.

> Below code is provided for demo only on how you can do thing like in screen shot . It is advised to use `flex` or `grid` to get the desired result as it will provide more control over content rendering

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section-container {
  width: 100%;
  column-width: 30%;
  column-gap: 3%;
  column-count: 3;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

li {
  list-style-position: inside
}
```

```html
<div class="section-container">
  <ul class="selection-list">
    <div class="item-group">
      <label>What symptoms are they experiencing?</label><br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="depPresent[]" id="depPresent" value="anxiety" />Depressed Mood
      <br />Severity: &nbsp;
      <label for="sxDepMild"><input type="radio" name="sxDep" id="sxDepMild" value="mild" required />Mild &emsp;</label><br />
      <label for="sxDepModerate"><input type="radio" name="sxDep" id="sxDepModerate" value="moderate" required />Moderate  &emsp;</label><br />
      <label for="sxDepSevere"><input type="radio" name="sxDep" id="sxDepSevere" value="severe" required />Severe &emsp; </label><br />
      <label for="sxDepMild"><input type="radio" name="sxDep" id="sxDepMild" value="mild" required />Mild &emsp;</label><br />
      <label for="sxDepModerate"><input type="radio" name="sxDep" id="sxDepModerate" value="moderate" required />Moderate  &emsp;</label><br />
      <label for="sxDepSevere"><input type="radio" name="sxDep" id="sxDepSevere" value="severe" required />Severe &emsp; </label><br />
      <label for="sxDepMild"><input type="radio" name="sxDep" id="sxDepMild" value="mild" required />Mild &emsp;</label><br />
      <label for="sxDepModerate"><input type="radio" name="sxDep" id="sxDepModerate" value="moderate" required />Moderate  &emsp;</label><br />
      <label for="sxDepSevere"><input type="radio" name="sxDep" id="sxDepSevere" value="severe" required />Severe &emsp; </label>
      <br />Notes:
      <li><input type="text" name="depNotes[]" id="depNotes" value="" /></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually didn't work. It made 3 columns, but it put the symptom and rating in column 1, the "Notes:" in column 2, and the text field for notes in column 3. I need it to look like the mock-up screen shot I put in the problem. Thank you for trying to help though.

Comment: It is provided for demo only on how you can do thing like in screen shot . It is advised to use `flex` or `grid` to get the desired result as it will provide more control over content rendering